# i have installed gperftools-2.0, but i can't get cpu profile statistics

Tags: c++, profiler, gperftools

i have installed gperftools-2.0, but i can't get cpu profile statistics

following is my steps to get the statistics:

1. install gperftools
   tar -xzvfj gperftools-2.0.tar.gz

2.edit cpp file test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gperftools/profiler.h>

int main()
{
        ProfilerStart("test.prof");

        for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        {
                printf("hello world!");
        }

        ProfilerStop();

        return 0;
}
```

1. compile
   g++ test.cpp -o test -O0 -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lprofiler
2. run
   ./test
3. report
   pprof ./test --text test.prof

whose output is:
Using local file ./test.
Using local file test.prof.

what's wrong in my steps?

Comment: did u solve ur problem?

Comment: The CPU time is essentially nothing, compared to the I/O time, so there's little for the profiler to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You just need your program run a little longer time, As the Google profiler just update the CPU statistics info every interval time.  Reset the "CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY" or "CPUPROFILE_REALTIME" value can change this interval time.